# Handing Missing Value (None) with Loc So It Replaced with None Instead of Complaining Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, pandas

I have the following pandas data frame (df):

```
          gene_id       chrom      start        end
0         EN02          1           577        647
1         EN12          2           648       1601
2         EN15          3          1602       1670
3         EN86          4          1671       3229
```

and list of indexes as follows:

```
ls_indx = [0, 1, 3, None]
```

I want to do the following to find those indices in the data frame like the following:

```
genes_snp = df. gene_id[overlaps]
```

When I excute it I got the following error:

```
KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Index([None])
```

I understand what the error means but I want to get the result with those indices that are matched in the data frame as well as those that are missing and I need those to be kept and labeled as missing:

```
    gene_id
0        EN02
1        EN12
3        EN86
4        None
```

How can I do this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `reindex`

```
ls_indx = [0, 1, 3, None]
df.gene_id.reindex(ls_indx)
Out[40]: 
0      EN02
1      EN12
3      EN86
NaN     NaN
Name: gene_id, dtype: object
```

Comment: you are faster than me :) +1

Comment: Great but when I write the resulting dataframe to a file, it doesn't include None for the missing values but instead blanks, why is that ?.

Comment: @aBiologist ummm what type of file it is ? did you assign it back before write into file ?

Comment: Never mind I fixed that from within the df.to_csv by assigning na_rep="None" and it worked, maybe there would a better solution. Your answer is great, thanks for your solution and for your quick response. I will accept your answer, @BEN_YO for the rescue 

Comment: @aBiologista yw :-) happy coding ~